# Rsync to a WebDAV filesystem on OS X copies all files regardless of being changed or not

Tags: macos, iphone, ipad, rsync, webdav

I am trying to sync from my (Mac) desktop to an iPad and an iPhone. MacOS X mounts WebDAV as a native file system, but syncing results in all files in my directory structure being copied again.

This occurs when I use `rsync -a`  or even a simple `rsync -r`. Various iPhone apps use the WebDAV server in iOS to transfer files. This occurs on several iPhone apps I use, including GoodReader.

Comment: Use `--itemize-changes` to find out why the file/directory has been synchronised. If the second character is a `t`, it was a different time, etc. See `man rsync`.

Comment: is there a WebDav server in iPhone OS????

Answer (score 0):

-ru options work for me.

This is an excerpt of explanation for -u, --update  option from `man rsync`:

> This  forces  rsync  to  skip any files which exist on the destination and have a modified time that is newer than the source file.  (If an existing destination file has a modification time equal to the  source  file's, it will be updated if the sizes are different.)